# Bootstrap 4 same height columns background

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Used bootstrap4 flex for a simple layout

```
col1 col2 sidebar
col3 col4
...  ...
```

The layout works as expected, columns are equal height. But if some columns have more content than others, I cannot set the background. If I set the background at the column level, I miss the gap between columns (bootstrap uses padding for separation), if I set background on internal div of the column, the background doesn't fill the height of the column.

Is there a trick to have all the columns with full background?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: How about creating a [bootply](http://bootply.com/new) to demonstrate the code?